# SQLServerで、あるSQLがどんなロックをかけるのかを確認したい

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQLServer2016 Standardを使っています。
あるSQLが、どんなロックをかける（かけた）のかを確認する手段は無いでしょうか？

- ロック対象（テーブル、インデックス）
- ロックのレベル（RID、KEY、ページ、テーブル）
- ロックの種類（SとかUとかIXとか）

「今どんなロックがかかっているか」を調べる方法は知っています。
[こういうの](https://www.excellence-blog.com/2016/11/11/sqlserver%E3%81%AE%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8Bsql/)です。

そうではなく、「このSQLを実行したら、最初から最後までにどんなロックがかかる／かかったのか」を知りたいです。
実行計画の詳細情報として見れたりしないかなと思うのですが・・・
（統計情報等で変動しうることは織り込み済みです）

どなたかご存知でしたら教えてください。

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler は、試してみましたか？

Comment: SQLServerプロファイラで採取できるとは知りませんでした。Lock:Acquiredイベントですかね・・・試してみましたが、見方が分からず。結構大量に出てきましたが、「今実行したSQL自体によるロックか？」も判別できていません（SSMSから実行しました）。教えていただいたMSの資料を読み込んでみます。継続して他の回答を募集します。できれば実行計画にそった形で出力されるとわかりやすいのですが・・・

Comment: [SQL Server のロックのエスカレーションが原因で発生するブロッキング問題を解決する方法](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/323630/how-to-resolve-blocking-problems-that-are-caused-by-lock-escalation-in)
ロックのエスカレーションは、粒度が細かい多数のロック (行ロックやページ ロックなど) をテーブル ロックに変換する処理です。
パフォーマンスが改善されるような場面、または過度のシステム ロック メモリをより適切なレベルまで下げる必要があるときにのみ、ロックのエスカレーションが発生します。
ロックのエスカレーションが発生しているかどうかを判断するには、`Lock:Escalation` イベントを含む SQL プロファイラのトレースを開始します